# threejs - gpgpu/rtt example redundant lines

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, gpgpu

I really liked the [gpgpu demo](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html) found among the threejs examples. While playing around with the shaders, trying to build a particle-in-cell simulator, I soon noticed that I don't need to update the texture uniforms manually for changing the particles' positions.
I proceeded to download the example code, and found that the following lines seem to be redundant:

```
if (!paused) {
                simulator.simulate( delta );

                birdUniforms.texturePosition.value = simulator.currentPosition;//redundant?
                birdUniforms.textureVelocity.value = simulator.currentVelocity;//redundant?
            }
```

Now I wonder where else these values are set instead, could someone with a broader understanding of threejs tell me where to look? While my application works perfectly so far, it really vexes me that I don't understand why...

EDIT: is there a way to find out when/where uniforms are being updated inside threejs?trying to log the respective material's uniforms always returns null. Is it even possible to update a shader's uniforms without using shadermaterial?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that example was refactored at one point to hide some of the GPGPU implementation details inside the `SimulationRenderer` -- in particular, the ping-ponging -- and there is some left-over code in the main body. In fact, `birdUniforms` is not used.

Maybe you can improve the example.

three.js r.66

Comment: hey! thanks for your answer!
Indeed the uniforms can be left out all together. Still the two sampler2D uniforms inside the birdVS-shader are being updated from somewhere. In the SimulationRenderer however, I didn't find code referring to the birdVS Shader. I also find it perplexing that changing the uniforms' names inside the birdVS Shader does not affect the functionality at all. Or am I not seeing something?

Comment: @cacahuananche I did that too - rename the uniforms' names.  Cannot for the life of me figure out what's updating those positions and velocities.  How on earth does birdVS know about the updates in the simulation?